# Mapping Rows To Columns From a Partitioned Value Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with the following structure:

| set_id | value | set_row_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 1 |
| 1 | Bar | 2 |
| 1 | Baz | 3 |
| 2 | Foo2 | 1 |
| 2 | Bar2 | 2 |
| 2 | Baz2 | 3 |
| 2 | Qux2 | 4 |
| 2 | Thud2 | 5 |
| 3 | Foo3 | 1 |

I would like to take this data and place it into a new table where the number of columns matches the max number of values in one set, the value with `set_row_number` of `1` will always be in the column called `start_node` and the maximum `set_row_number` in the set will always be in the column called `end_node`. Any other middle `set_row_number`s should fill in from max `set_row_number` - 1 starting with `1_from_end_node`, `2_from_end_node`, etc.

The end result should like like:

| start_node | 3_from_end_node | 2_from_end_node | 1_from_end_node | end_node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | NULL | NULL | Bar | Baz |
| Foo2 | Bar2 | Baz2 | Qux2 | Thud2 |
| Foo3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I have already tried to use `PIVOT` to accomplish this but I have not been able to get expected results due to the variable length sets and the requirement to have the first in a specific column and the max `set_row_number` in another.

I can change the structure of the starting table, if needed. This table was derived from another table that had the hierarchy in a pipe separated format. I used `CROSS_APPLY STRING_SPLIT(hierarchy_data, '|')` to achieve my starting point below.

Thanks in advance to anyone able to help. Please let me know if additional clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it *statically*, which is only useful if you know that there will never be more than 5 nodes for any `set_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT start_node = src.value, the_rest.value, 
         col = CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN 'end_node'
         ELSE CONCAT(the_rest.rn, '_from_end_node') END
  FROM dbo.[a table] AS src
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY set_id ORDER BY set_row_number DESC)-1
    FROM dbo.[a table] AS rel
    WHERE rel.set_id = src.set_id
       AND rel.set_row_number > 1
  ) AS the_rest WHERE src.set_row_number = 1
)
AS x 
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR col IN 
(
  [3_from_end_node], 
  [2_from_end_node], 
  [1_from_end_node], 
  [end_node]
)) AS p;
```

Results from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0TGnDqKi):

| start_node | 3_from_end_node | 2_from_end_node | 1_from_end_node | end_node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | *null* | *null* | Bar | Baz |
| Foo2 | Bar2 | Baz2 | Qux2 | Thud2 |
| Foo3 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

If you have to plan for any number of nodes (well, up to 255 probably, then you get into query text and parsing/compiling limits), you'll have to use dynamic SQL. Here's one way to do that (similar results in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e6EiEEEB)):

```
DECLARE @num tinyint, @cols nvarchar(max);

SELECT @num = MAX(c) - 2 FROM 
  (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[a table] GROUP BY set_id) AS x;

;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE('.',@num-1),'.')x
),
f AS
(
  SELECT rn, col = QUOTENAME(CONCAT(rn, '_from_end_node'))
  FROM src
)
SELECT @cols = (SELECT col + N',' FROM f 
  ORDER BY rn DESC
  FOR XML PATH(''),
  TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM src;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT start_node = src.value, the_rest.value, 
             col = CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN ''end_node''
             ELSE CONCAT(the_rest.rn, ''_from_end_node'') END
      FROM dbo.[a table] AS src
      OUTER APPLY
      (
        SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY set_id ORDER BY set_row_number DESC)-1
        FROM dbo.[a table] AS rel
        WHERE rel.set_id = src.set_id
           AND rel.set_row_number > 1
      ) AS the_rest WHERE src.set_row_number = 1
    )
    AS x 
    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR col IN 
    (' + @cols + N'[end_node])) AS p;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```